# Parsing multiple Json Objects in android

Tags: android, json

I am trying to send this json to web server:

```
[{"codemenu":"1","name":"Fried Rice"},
{"codemenu":"2","name":"Hongkong Fried Rice"},
{"codemenu":"3","name":"Special fried Rice"}]
```

This is the code but it's not working:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/pnir_restoran/test.php");
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
try {
    // JSON data:
    json.put("codemenu", "1");
    json.put("name", "friedrice");
    json.put("codemenu", "2");
    json.put("name", "Hongkong friedrice");
    json.put("codemenu", "3");
    json.put("name", "Special friedrice");          

    JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
    postjson.put(json); //i cant use postjson.add(json);

    // Post the data:
    httppost.setHeader("json",json.toString());
    httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    System.out.print(json);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

What should I do? Please help me.

Comment: Have you displayed the JSON that's being generated?  What you're generating is not what you say you want.

Comment: (You're creating one JSON object and putting 6 entries in it.  The JSON prototype you list contains 3 objects, each with 2 entries.)

Comment: (It also doesn't make sense that you're putting the JSON object in the header and the array in the params.)

Comment: yes that json that i want read in php @HotLicks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) and then put individual [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)s inside the array:

```
// Initialize the JSON Array and your three seperate objects.
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject jObj1 = new JSONObject();
JSONObject jObj2 = new JSONObject();
JSONObject jObj3 = new JSONObject();

// Put elements in one object at a time and put them in your array.
jObj1.put("codemenu", "1");
jObj1.put("name", "friedrice");

jsonArray.put(jObj1);

jObj2.put("codemenu", "2");
jObj2.put("name", "Hongkong friedrice");

jsonArray.put(jObj2);

jObj3.put("codemenu", "3");
jObj3.put("name", "Special friedrice");

jsonArray.put(jObj3);
```

Comment: but thats is static what should i do if the data is 100 i cant make the array of json object ,  @Tushar Dhoot

Comment: @stefan Use a loop with the code that needs to be repeated inside.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing all JSON handling manually, you can use [Spring Android's RestTemplate module](http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html).